# String concat failed in tcp thread

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

This is my code

```
while (true)
{
    byte[] btServerReceive = new byte[256];
    TcpClient tcpclient = tcp.AcceptTcpClient();
    NetworkStream ns = tcpclient.GetStream();
    int intReceiveLength = ns.Read(btServerReceive, 0, btServerReceive.Length);

    string recv = Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312").GetString(btServerReceive) + "_01";        
    tcpclient.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(recv.ToString());

    // Create a new thread to handle the data associate with recv
    Thread sendUpThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SendThread));
    sendUpThread.Start(recv);
}
```

The string `recv` only get the value of `Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312").GetString(btServerReceive)`, can't add `"_01"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* add the "_01". It's just that you don't notice, because the string is being displayed in a  context where the embedded nulls prevent you from seeing it.

I.e. you've passed a 256-byte array to the `GetString()` method, where only the first N bytes have actually been modified and the rest still have their initial value of 0. So `GetString()` interprets those as '\0' characters and faithfully includes those in the returned string.

At a minimum, you would have to do something like this:

```
string recv = Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312")
    .GetString(btServerReceive, 0, intReceiveLength) + "_01";
```

I.e. take into account the number of bytes you actually received and only decode that many.

Now that said, even that doesn't solve your problem entirely. The above will probably work most of the time, but TCP could return to you only part of a whole string that was sent. Since you're using UTF8 encoding, some characters are represented by more than one byte and so of course the last byte in the data received could be only part of a character.

To fix this, you need to have some way to know when you're done reading a string (e.g. send null-terminated strings, send length-prefixed strings, fixed-length strings, etc.), or maintain a single instance of a `Decoder` which you use to decode the text as it comes in (`Decoder` maintains an internal buffer of incompletely decoded data so that on subsequent calls to decode text, it can correctly handle the partial character).

Comment: thanks very much,I've learned.   It Let me confused a night .....thank you very much